After upgrading to 24.04 label from buttons on the settings menu (wifi, wired, etc) disappeared
After upgrading from 23.10 to 24.04 the labels of various items on the settings menu simply disappeared . The buttons are still working but, since they are empty, I need to click on each of them to find their function.
Changing between dark and light style doesn't change the behavior.

The reported behavior disappeared in the last system update.
